# ASP.NET MVC Displaying a user's roles as comma separated string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I would like to display a list of my users in ASP.NET MVC5 and in a column I would like to display every role which the user has (comma separated).

So I have a simple UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string AdatlapNev { get; set; }
        public string Roles { get; set; }

    }
```

In my View, the model is: @model `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>`

The problem is with the displaying of the roles. I tried to do it this way:

```
public ActionResult UserList()
        {
            return View(db.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
            {
                AdatlapNev = u.Adatlap == null ? "NULL" : u.Adatlap.Nev,
                Email = u.Email,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => db.Roles.Find(r.RoleId).Name).Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " + s2)
        }
            ));
        }
```

But it doesn't work. I get `System.ArgumentException` which says that I can't use the `Find` method here.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Untested, but try something like `Roles = String.Join(", ", u.Roles.Select(r => r.Name))`.

Comment: @SteveGreene The 'IdentityUserRole' class doesn't have a 'Name' parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a solution which works.

```
// GET: Admin/UserList
        public ActionResult UserList()
        {
            var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));

            var q = db.Users.Select(u => new
            {
                AdatlapNev = u.Adatlap == null ? "NULL" : u.Adatlap.Nev,
                Email = u.Email,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.RoleId)
            });

            var roles = db.Roles.Select(r => new { Id = r.Id, Name = r.Name }).ToList();

            return View(q.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new UserViewModel
            {
                AdatlapNev = x.AdatlapNev,
                Email = x.Email,
                UserName = x.UserName,
                Roles = String.Join(", ", x.Roles.Select(j => roles.Where(r => r.Id == j).Single().Name))
            }));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need a RoleManager to get the name:

```
public ActionResult UserList()
{

    var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db));

    return View(
        db.Users.Select(u => new UserViewModel
        {
            AdatlapNev = u.Adatlap == null ? "NULL" : u.Adatlap.Nev,
            Email = u.Email,
            UserName = u.UserName,
            Roles = String.Join(", ", u.Roles.Select(r => rm.FindById(r.RoleId).Name))
        })


    );
}
```

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Comment: Still doesn't work: `System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole FindById[IdentityRole,String](Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager'2[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole,System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
db.Roles.Where(x => u.Roles.Any(y => x == y.RoleId)).Select(x => x.Name)
```

instead of

```
u.Roles.Select(r => db.Roles.Find(r.RoleId).Name)
```

Comment: I get System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.' in the View when I try to display the lines with a foreach loop.